# How to hide URL from <a> tag, so it's not showing in HTML to bots and visitors

Tags: html, jquery, css

Is there a simple way in CSS/HTML or jquery to hide url from external views, but still keep link clickable, so URL opens only when user actually clicked.

Ex. [Link to Page](http://www.google.com)

Label shows but url is not.

Comment: Use a JavaScript `click` listener that does `window.location = "URL"`

Comment: Why would you want that? What practical purpose would something like that serve?

Comment: I would want it so the machines or people don't see the url without clicking on it, so they don't just download a list of links easy way. It's also useful when website has to pay for every link clicked to minimize a risk that a bot or competition will actually download links and keep on clicking. Also hiding link will not mess up the SEO and not give unnecessary credit to a third company. HTML future should have this. Thank you Caleb Carson for a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to display javascript:void(0) in the link to hide it, then when the user clicks it will send them to the website you want.

```html
  <head>
    <title>Hide URL Example</title>
    <style>
      .link {
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Here is a <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link" data-url="http://www.google.com/">Link to Page</a>
    </p>
```

```js
    <script>
      const links = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
      links.forEach((link) => {
        link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          const url = link.getAttribute('data-url');
          window.location.href = url;
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use The Window Location Object:

```js
function myFunction() {
  location.href = "http://www.yoururl.com";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Take me to your url</button>
```

Comment: For some reason the url is putting subfolder into the url and not showing the value. It redirects to link like domain.com/public/$variable, instead of www.link.com URL is a value from a variable, and it works inside a simple <a> tag